# Salesforce to Salesforce API - call apex methods

Tags: integration

Salesforce Production org 1 -

```
Class AccountUtil
{
    public String ValidateAccount(String AccountName)
    {
        //validation logic
        return 'validation result';
    }
}
```

Salesforce Production Org 2 - has all accounts and data.

I want to call AccountUtil.ValidateAccount('Test Company'); method from Salesforce org 2 in apex is it possible ?

I am interested in options other than SOAP web-service.

Comment: What org do you want the apex code to run against, org1 or org2?

Comment: @RyanGuest is Production to Production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use REST API .All you need is to do an oauth between the two systems and then you can call any exposed API

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com

Refer the above documents for oauth 2.0 implementation.

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST

Follow the above to understand how to create the API.

Sample REST API class

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Demorest/')
global Class AccountUtil{
@HttpGet
public String ValidateAccount(){
    String AccountName =RestContext.request.params.get('accountname');
    //validation logic
    return 'validation result';
  }
 }
```