# No service available for class for Soap call

Tags: api, soap-api, webservices, soap

I'm searching a simple Webservice test on Salesforce. I created a simple WS

```
global class AccountPlan {

   webservice String area; 
   webservice String region; 

   //Define an object in apex that is exposed in apex web service
   global class Plan {
      webservice String name;
      webservice Integer planNumber;
      webservice Date planningPeriod;
      webservice string planId;
   }

   webservice static Plan createAccountPlan(Plan vPlan) {

   //A plan maps to the Account object in salesforce.com. 
   //So need to map the Plan class object to Account standard object
   Account acct = new Account();
   acct.Name = vPlan.name;
   acct.AccountNumber = String.valueOf(vPlan.planNumber);
   insert acct;
   vPlan.planId=acct.Id;
   return vPlan;
  }
}
```

And i'm searching to call it using SoapUI (4.6.0) making a Simple soap call.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:acc="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/AccountPlan">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <acc:AllowFieldTruncationHeader>
      </acc:AllowFieldTruncationHeader>
      <acc:SessionHeader>
         <acc:sessionId>00D20000000leM4!AQUAQAbbtdrNRt4vK7SaJ8e2VPefMhAFfTtgDpvKI_8JZlyHJhKOBfCmU6tDiaf4FQau2A1Ni9n9OJbuzR8j1n.zt7n7zcHb</acc:sessionId>
      </acc:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <acc:createAccountPlan>
         <acc:vPlan>
            <acc:name>Klodjan Test</acc:name>
            <acc:planNumber>2</acc:planNumber>
         </acc:vPlan>
      </acc:createAccountPlan>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and I'm receiving the follow feedback

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>No service available for class 'AccountPlan'</faultstring>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Any one can help me to understand why i'm geting such error... I'm running as system adinistrator...

Comment: what URL are you sending the request to?

Comment: Sorry what you mean whith what URL? I imported the WSDL of the WS in Soap UI and tried to send the soap message above. I suppose that the message is send to "http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/AccountPlan"

Comment: its HTTP, so the request goes to a URL. You should be able to see it in Soap UI somewhere. Also did you give the user access to the apex class in their profile?

Comment: Yes the class is visible to the use profile, and also the profile has the api enabled... I'm actually using as request the XML above, i send it using soap UI.  I have anything to change... That is the XML generated importing the WSDL

I tried to call the WS also from another Salesforce sandbox, but I recieve the same error as using Soap Ui

Comment: Actually I made the WS public adding the class to sites, and it works properly... so I'm understanding less than before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine for me.  This is the response I got:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/AccountPlan"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <soapenv:Body>
      <createAccountPlanResponse>
      <result>
        <name>Klodjan Test</name>
        <planId>001F000001ABD9RIAX</planId>
        <planningPeriod xsi:nil="true"/>
        <planNumber>2</planNumber>
     </result>
  </createAccountPlanResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would ask, do you have a namespace defined in your org? If so, you would need to modify your endpoint to include the namespace as well.
The only other thought would be if you have a proxy in place to access the internet, you need to have the proxy configured correctly in SOAPUI as well.

Comment: My money is on namespace.

Comment: Hi, boh I do not understand what happened. I had installed on sandbox just the MobilePack_jQuery package. I removed it, and now works fine. After that I installed again the package to understand if was that the problem, but now works also with the package installed! so I dont understand... mystery... @JimRae I'mgiving you the bounty because looks in someway to do with what you wrote... but for me is not still clear what happened. have any sense for you ? best regards, Klodjan

Comment: Thank you.  Again, my thought is that the package you had installed somehow impacted your code. Likely,  related to the inclusion of a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

you can check this answer which has documentation reference on how to accomplish something similar but using REST, it involves slightly more coding but it's more beautiful:) (users authenticate via the oauth2 flow, which will have to be built)

[Salesforce to Salesforce API - call apex methods](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5710/salesforce-to-salesforce-api-call-apex-methods)